# Help with a multilevel menu with json and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, json, menu, multi-level

I'm trying to do a multilevel menu that slides when ">" is clicked. The first issue is that the CSS is not working properly, the < ul >'s aren't getting floated to the left.

What I'm needing is show only one ul, and if ">" is clicked show the "children" menu sliding it or showing it, any method is useful.

The complete code ready to test is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/seinoxygen/CxBrW/)

I'm trying to do this: [menu](http://www.slashc.com/codecanyon/jquery_infinite_sliding_menu/index.html)

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var json = [{"id":"1","parent":"0","slug":"digitalart","name":"Digital Art"},{"id":"2","parent":"1","slug":"3d","name":"3-Dimensional Art"},{"id":"39","parent":"1","slug":"drawings","name":"Drawings"},{"id":"3","parent":"2","slug":"abstract","name":"Abstract"},{"id":"4","parent":"2","slug":"characters","name":"Characters"},{"id":"12","parent":"2","slug":"objects","name":"Objects"},{"id":"23","parent":"2","slug":"scenes","name":"Scenes"},{"id":"32","parent":"2","slug":"unsorted","name":"Unsorted"},{"id":"33","parent":"2","slug":"vehicles","name":"Vehicles"},{"id":"5","parent":"4","slug":"creatures","name":"Animals & Creatures"},{"id":"6","parent":"4","slug":"cartoon","name":"Cartoon"},{"id":"7","parent":"4","slug":"female","name":"Female"},{"id":"8","parent":"4","slug":"groups","name":"Groups"},{"id":"9","parent":"4","slug":"machines","name":"Machines & Robots"},{"id":"10","parent":"4","slug":"male","name":"Male"},{"id":"11","parent":"4","slug":"misc","name":"Miscellaneus"}];
    build_menu(json, 0);
});

function build_menu(json, parent){
    var menu;
    var item = "";
    var counter = 0;
    if(parent != '0'){
        item += '<li><a class="more" onClick="show(); return false;" href="#">Back</a></li>';
    }
    $.each(json, function(i, category) {
        if(category.parent == parent){
            var more = '<a class="more" onClick="show('+parent+'); return false;" href="#">></a>';

            item = item + '<li>' + category.name + more + '</li>';
            build_menu(json, category.id);
            counter++;
        }
    });

    if(counter > 0){    
        menu = '<ul class="menu" id="category' + parent + '">' + item + '</ul>';
        $('#menu').prepend(menu);
    }
}

function show(id){
    $(".menu").hide();
    $("#category"+id).show();
}
```

css

```
#menu{
    width: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu ul{
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li{
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#menu li .more{
    //float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

html

```
<div id="menu">
</div>
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the menu? It works fine on your example. What you mean by "the 's aren't getting floated to the left"

Comment: @SeinOxygen your bounty has been met :-)

Comment: @SeinOxygen your bounty has been met

Comment: All the jsfiddle links listed here seem to have expired....Could someone please psot them again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved.

Use jQuery:

```
build_menu(json, 0);
    $('.back').hide();
    $('ul').not('.parent').hide();
});

function build_menu(json, parent, parentID) {
    var menu, li;
    var item = $('<ul class="menu ' + (parent == '0' ? 'parent' : '') + '" id="category' + parent + '"></ul>');
    var counter = 0;
    if (parent != '0') {
        li = $('<li><a class="back" href="#">Back</a></li>');
        li.click(function() {
            $('.back').hide();
            $("#category" + parentID).show();
            $("#category" + parent).hide();
            $('.back', $("#category" + parentID)).show();
            return false;
        })

        li.appendTo(item);
    }
    $.each(json, function(i, category) {
        if (category.parent == parent) {
            var more = $('<a class="more" href="#">></a>');
            more.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('.back', $("#category" + category.id)).show();
                $("#category" + category.id).show();
                $("#category" + parent).hide();
                console.log("#category" + category.id, $("#category" + category.id));
                if ($("#category" + category.id).length <= 0) { //NO CHILDREN
                    $('.back').hide();
                    $("#category" + parent).show();
                    $('.back', $("#category" + parent)).show();
                }
                return false;
            })
            li = $('<li>' + category.name + '</li>');
            more.appendTo(li);
            li.appendTo(item);
            build_menu(json, category.id, parent);
            counter++;
        }
    });

    if (counter > 0) {
        menu = item;
        $('#menu').prepend(menu);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/CxBrW/25/
Fiddle with slide animations: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/CxBrW/26/

**UPDATE**:

Here is fiddle with no carrots if no children: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/CxBrW/36/

Comment: @Neal Everything? If i click on > on digital drawings it MUST show "3-Dimensional Art" and "Drawings" and if i click on "3-Dimensional Art" it should show "Abstract", "Characters", "Objects"...

Comment: @Blaya, i made the menu stop when it reached a point where the menu had no more children

Comment: @Neal, its perfect! If you could hide the ">" link when the category dont have childrens you get all the points :P

Comment: @Blaya, that might not be too easy, few minutes

Comment: @Neal I noticed that if i use build_menu(json, 1); it Dont generate the menu showing the childs and the back link.

Comment: @Blaya its all there (if you inspect element in chrome) just there is nothing that has the class `parent` that would be shown. I only add the class `parent` (in the code) if it is `0`

Comment: @Neal Yeah i ts there indeed but it doesn't show. If i need to show a specific category from default i cant because appead hidden and i can't do anything about that because the code doen't allow pass anything but 0.

Comment: @Blaya, here is an updated fiddle that starts with one: http://jsfiddle.net/CxBrW/37/   notice the extra parameter in the function

Comment: Fiddlesticks, your fine Fiddles give frustrating Four-Oh-Fours! :(

Comment: @erik, why yes they do... odd, one minute, ill try to fix

Comment: @erik, this is really odd, where did they go?

Comment: @blaya, do you have the code so i can recreate the fiddles for future users?